# Displaying Authenticated Users Details In ASP.NET on MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently developing a basic system for storing health care details (only for practise, will not be used for live data). Using MVC 4 and VS 2012. 
System is published to Windows Azure and works (login/registration). 
I have created an area to display details entered into the system however, currently ALL users details are displayed at once when a logged in user view the page.
I would like for only the authenticated users details to be displayed. I'm sure its down to the 'foreach' statement but I'm not sure what to replace it with?
Code

```
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
 {
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SecondName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
        </td>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you show the code in the controller?

Comment: @Patrick The comment says its too long, so here it is in txt on DropBox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bmil4z7awkmaxh/StackOverFlowNote.txt

Comment: I think you should rise your knowledge of MVC and C#. Now you are itterating over a list. You need to make a link between the medical history and the user (by userid). Then you need to make a controller method that filters on that user id after the user is loged in and give the data back in a model. For a nice example how to build webapps in mvc google for the nerddinner tutorial.